# Issue with adding ngMaterial as a module

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am seeing this error:

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile
```

All I am doing is this (I have additional code for other modules, just adding the relevant ones here):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        //Angular modules
        'ngRoute',
        'ngMaterial',

        //third-party modules
        'firebase',
    ])
    .config(configFunction)
    .run(runFunction);
```

Any idea what is going on ?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the reference for firebase

Comment: firebase is not an issue. If I remove ngMaterial from the list, I do not see any error.

Comment: I have just added the relevant code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the versions are same,

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
```

here is the working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/s33RpP?p=preview)

Comment: I just figured this out. Thanks for helping out though.